# Matrix transform: Converting SVG path coordinates to Leaflet coordinate system

Tags: javascript, matrix, svg, leaflet, linear-algebra

The short version: How can I add SVG paths to a Leaflet map in such a way that the paths will update when the map coordinates change (e.g. on zoom change or slide)?

The long version: Hello, I have a topographic [image](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gathering-a-building/2000_Cooper_Robertson_G_cutout1.tif) that contains building outlines. After geo-rectifying the image I used Photoshop to convert the raster data to [SVG](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gathering-a-building/2000_Cooper_Robertson_G_cutout1.svg). I know the geo-coordinates of the bounding box that describe the SVG perimeter, and know the internal coordinates of SVG path elements. I'm wondering the best way to now add the buildings described in the path elements of the SVG above to a Leaflet map.

Here's a fiddle that shows the bounding box of the SVG image in red and the buildings in blue: http://jsfiddle.net/duhaime/4vL925Lj/ As you can see, the buildings are not yet properly oriented with respect to the bounding box.

My initial plan to align the buildings was to use a one-time script to convert the path elements from the SVG coordinate system into lat, long coordinates, then draw the buildings on the map using the polyline function I used to draw the bounding box:

```
var polyline = L.polyline(
  [upperLeft, upperRight, lowerRight, lowerLeft, upperLeft], 
  {color: 'red', className: 'bounding-box', weight: 2}
).addTo(map);
```

The trouble with this approach is that Leaflet polylines can't draw Bezier curves, which are present in the SVG path elements above. As a workaround, I thought I could use linear approximations for the Bezier curves, though this might become a decent amount of work.

Eventually I realized the SVG for the bounding box in the fiddle above uses Bezier curves, which gave me the idea that I might instead use matrix transforms to transpose the coordinate space of the building SVGs into the Leaflet coordinate space. The fiddle above uses a sample matrix transform css rule to transform the building layer.

Before going further down this rabbit hole, I wanted to ask: What do others think is the best way to add the paths that describe the buildings in the SVG above to the Leaflet map in the fiddle? I would be very grateful for any advice others can offer on this question!

**PROGRESS:** I decided to simplify this problem and figure out how to use a matrix transform to transform one div ("A") into the aspect ratio of another div ("B"). In doing so, I made a small [Python script](https://gist.github.com/duhaime/6195b082ac5fd34a0112c7e7b391baf7) that takes as input the input div A's pixel coordinates and the desired output div B's pixel coordinates. This script generates the transform matrix X such that AX=B. The script is documented internally and has an accompanying [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/duhaime/9444Lnjp/).

I also made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/duhaime/384b26d9665a65f67ce405c3ad43ff51) that derives the transform matrix to project points from the SVG space into proper lat, lng coords. Worst case scenario, I can partition the SVG path elements, take the dot product of each point with the transform matrix, and draw polylines with leaflet to plot the buildings. That will of lose the Bezier curves though...

Comment: Have you seen the D3 + Leaflet example? I'm not sure but think it might cover your use case: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/

Comment: Thanks @Snorfalorpagus! In that example Mike reads in geojson data, but I have raw SVG data that doesn't yet contain geographic information...

Comment: OK, maybe I'll join you in the rabbit hole. One additional thingy needed in your raw svg: Include a current street's center line that also exists in your historical drawing.

Comment: Came across this project that claims to implement Bezier curves in Leaflet: https://github.com/elfalem/Leaflet.curve

Comment: the svg ([2000_Cooper_Robertson_G_cutout1_full.svg](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gathering-a-building/2000_Cooper_Robertson_G_cutout1_full.svg)) used on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/duhaime/9444Lnjp/) is no longer available.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my S3 was getting huge so I culled lots of things. Not sure I could find this again...

Answer (score 3):

This took quite a bit of thinking, but I've found a solution.

After reading around, I realized that one can transpose points from one coordinate space (e.g. the SVG coordinate space) to another (e.g. and the lat/long coordinate space) by identifying a transform matrix, then by multiplying each point in the input space (SVG) by that transform matrix. This operation will transpose the given point into the appropriate location in the map.

I wrote [this script](https://gist.github.com/duhaime/384b26d9665a65f67ce405c3ad43ff51) to calculate the required transform matrix. The script takes as parameters the SVG's bounding box coordinates and the bounding box coordinates of the georectified geotiff from which the SVG elements were extracted. The script generates the transform matrix and shows how one can multiply points in the SVG space by the matrix to find their appropriate lat/long coordinates.

There's a catch--one needs to have the points in the SVG represented without any kind of CSS transformation. To get a straightforward representation of a SVG point's location within the SVG, I converted path elements in the SVG to polygon elements using [this tool](https://betravis.github.io/shape-tools/path-to-polygon/), for which the [source](https://github.com/betravis/shape-tools/tree/master/path-to-polygon) is openly available.

In case others need to accomplish a similar task, here was the full workflow I used:

1. Find a raster map (jpg/tiff) of interest.
2. Georectify the map with QGIS, ArcGIS, or MapWarper. This produces a geotiff.
3. Download and install [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/), a powerful geospatial library with Python bindings.
4. Run an image trace on a feature of interest in your Geotiff (e.g. buildings) in Adobe Illustrator. This produces a vector layer; save the vector layer as a SVG file.
5. If there are any `<rect>` or other geometric shapes in your saved SVG, convert them to paths and re-save.
6. Identify the bounding box coordinates of your SVG and the Geotiff you fed as input to Illustrator. The bounding box of the latter can be obtained from GDAL by running `gdalinfo {your-geotiff-file.tif}`
7. Inline those bounding box coordinates in the script referenced above. Then partition your SVG into an array of `<polygon>` elements, and for each, split the polygon into an array of points. Multiply each point by the transform matrix to find the point's lat/long position.
8. Save each point of each shape to an appropriate geojson format so you can load the data into the client.

For what it's worth, the script I'm using for generating the matrix transform and for transposing `<polygon>` element points into lat/long space is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/YaleDHLab/gathering-a-building/master/app/utils/matrix-transform.py). Please note some paths in the script would need to be updated for your situation--e.g. the script pushes the output geojson to an S3 bucket my lab manages :)

I hope this helps someone else who finds themselves confronted with this task! I'm frankly amazed this took so much effort, and am pretty sure there must be a more elegant workflow...

Answer (score 1):

I added this feature to work I've previously done on Leaflet Maps. This may apply to your application.
See: [www.svgdiscovery.com/K/K04A.htm](http://www.svgdiscovery.com/K/K04A.htm)

This uses two key points that are common to both the Leaflet Map and the imported SVG paths.

Comment: Thanks Francis! When you inline the lat lng positions in the svg, how do you identify those positions (i.e. are they the top left corner of the path element, or something else?) Does each path element need lat lng coords? I'm trying to get your example working with the svg above...

Comment: Here's the fiddle I'm using to try and reproduce your example: https://jsfiddle.net/dduhaime/92xod5tt/4/

Comment: the Chrome browser recently(version 48) deprecated pathSegList and now requires a SVGPathSeg API polyfill
    Go to  https://github.com/progers/pathseg to obtain a copy, and place a call for it in your file <head>
    script block file call: type="text/javascript"  src='pathSeg.js'  This is needed for the function removePathPointTransform(path)

Comment: Or, you can include a remote call to my site... http://www.svgDiscovery.com/K/pathSeg.js

Comment: I ran this with your paths and worked OK for some of them. However, the d value structure crashes via removePathPointTransform(path) on many of them.The first 'crash' path element:<path d="M1137.78,1044.93l4.24-14.14h8.56c3,9.77-.87,18.09-2.66,27l-7.34,1.17-3.47,9.16c-4-.19-8.36.48-12.12-0.78-7.81-2.61-4.11-9.51-5.22-15.09a54.14,54.14,0,0,1-2.33,7.07c-0.45,1-2.16,2.1-3,1.9-1.38-.32-2.6-1.59-3.7-2.64-0.35-.34-0.13-1.27-0.18-1.93-0.62-8.9-1.27-17.8-1.8-26.7-0.07-1.17.54-2.38,0.93-4,8.36,1.51,7.81,8.18,8.78,14.56Z"/> I can't determine which values are not being handled. I'll test just this path.

Comment: Well, I processed your paths and they are much too verbose for the function to process them correctly. I guess I just can't help you on this project. Sorry.

Comment: No worries at all @FrancisHemsher! I'm going to give you a +1 for the reference to pathSeg--this library seems like it might be able to help me split a path element into an array of points. If so, I can take the dot product of those points' positions and the transform matrix to position them correctly, then just worry about updating positions on zoom or scroll. Thanks so much for giving this a go!

Answer (score 0):

The following example uses your polyline values to demonstrate the the approach as it would apply to svg paths and other shapes during zoom/pan of the Leaflet map.
Basically an SVG layer is created and all svg elements are added therein.

```html
<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#map {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

-->
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>



</body>
<script>

// create the map object itself
centerCoordinates = new L.LatLng(41.307, -72.928);

var map = new L.Map("map", {
  center: centerCoordinates,
  zoom: 14,
  zoomControl: false
});

// position the zoom controls in the bottom right hand corner
L.control.zoom({
  position: 'bottomright',
  zoom: 14,
  maxZoom: 20,
  minZoom: 12,
}).addTo(map);



map.addLayer(new L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>',
  subdomains: 'abcd',
  maxZoom: 19
}));

// specify the coordinates of the overlay's bounding box
var upperLeft = L.latLng(41.329785, -72.927220);
var lowerLeft = L.latLng(41.304414, -72.945686);
var upperRight = L.latLng(41.319186, -72.903268);
var lowerRight = L.latLng(41.293816, -72.921718);
/*
// create a red polyline from an array of LatLng points
var polyline = L.polyline(
  [upperLeft, upperRight, lowerRight, lowerLeft, upperLeft], {
    color: 'red',
    className: 'bounding-box',
    weight: 2
  }
).addTo(map);
*/

  //---CREATE SVG---
    map._initPathRoot() //---creates an svg layer---
    var MySVG=document.querySelector("svg") //---access svg element---

    var NS="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    //---place svg elems in here---
    var SvgElemG=document.createElementNS(NS,"g")
    MySVG.appendChild(SvgElemG)

     //---zooming the map's SVG elements---
    map.on("viewreset", adjustSVGElements);

//---add svg polygon---
var polygon=document.createElementNS(NS,"polyline")
polygon.setAttribute("stroke-width",1)
polygon.setAttribute("fill","none")
polygon.setAttribute("stroke","red")
 //---convert latLng to x,y---
var xyUL=map.latLngToLayerPoint(upperLeft)
var xyLL=map.latLngToLayerPoint(lowerLeft)
var xyLR=map.latLngToLayerPoint(lowerRight)
var xyUR=map.latLngToLayerPoint(upperRight)
var points=[xyUL.x,xyUL.y,xyLL.x,xyLL.y,xyLR.x,xyLR.y,xyUR.x,xyUR.y,xyUL.x,xyUL.y].toString()
polygon.setAttribute('points',points)

//--required for zoom---
var svgPnt=L.point(0,0) //--reference for translate--
var latLng=map.layerPointToLatLng(svgPnt)
var lat=latLng.lat
var lng=latLng.lng
polygon.setAttribute("lat",lat)
polygon.setAttribute("lng",lng)
//---retain the zoom level at its creation--
polygon.setAttribute('initZoom',map.getZoom())

SvgElemG.appendChild(polygon)

//--- on map zoom - fired via map event: viewreset---
function adjustSVGElements()
{
 var mapZoom=map.getZoom()

 var svgElems=SvgElemG.childNodes
 for(var k=0;k<svgElems.length;k++)
 {
        var svgElem=svgElems.item(k)
        var lat=parseFloat(svgElem.getAttribute("lat"))
        var lng=parseFloat(svgElem.getAttribute("lng"))
        var latLng= new  L.latLng(lat, lng)
        var transX=map.latLngToLayerPoint(latLng).x
        var transY=map.latLngToLayerPoint(latLng).y
        //---trash previous transform---
        svgElem.setAttribute("transform","") //---required for IE
        svgElem.removeAttribute("transform")

        var transformRequestObj=MySVG.createSVGTransform()
        var animTransformList=svgElem.transform
        //---get baseVal to access/place object transforms
        var transformList=animTransformList.baseVal
        //---translate----
        transformRequestObj.setTranslate( transX,  transY)
        transformList.appendItem(transformRequestObj)
        transformList.consolidate()
       //---scale---
        var initZoom=parseFloat(svgElem.getAttribute("initZoom"))
        var scale = (Math.pow(2, mapZoom)/2)/(Math.pow(2, initZoom)/2);
        transformRequestObj.setScale(scale,scale)
        transformList.appendItem(transformRequestObj)
        transformList.consolidate()
    }


}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @FrancisHemsher! Perhaps I'm overlooking something, but doesn't this approach take for granted the fact that we one has the lat long coordinates of the objects to be mapped? That seems to be the case, as you're leveraging the topleft, topright etc coordinates for the initial placement. My problem is I don't have these coordinates for the buildings themselves--I only know the latlong coordinates of the bounding box and the coordinates of objects within the SVG file that describe the building locations.

Comment: I'll take a try at working the rawsvg file's viewBox and initial placement of the paths...I'll let you know.

Comment: How do you determine the lat/lng of the initial polyline points?

Comment: The coordinates of the bounding box for the polyline were given to me, and I just drew the box that connects those points.

Comment: @duhaime I just can't shoehorn this in any elegant way. Sorry. I wonder if using Leaflet with OSMBuildings, and highlighting specific buildings, would be a more rational approach...

Comment: Thanks @FrancisHemsher, and no worries at all (I'm also still trying to figure this out). Unfortunately I have many maps to project, and they're almost all historical (eighteenth or nineteenth century). We should be able to find a workaround though...